# XAMPP PHP is not working

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have just installed XAMPP again, I was using IIS but I have now disabled that.

For some reason disabling it didn't seem to work, as the ports still clashed, so instead I have changed the port for Apache to "1234". 
As you can see from the control panel below XAMPP seems to be running just fine, the index page shows up fine at least.

[image: XAMPP Control Panel]

I made a quick test page and placed it in my install directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\testing.php)

```
<?
    $test = "hello world";
    echo $test;
?>
```

I then load this location in Chrome: `http://localhost:1234/testing.php`
But for some reason the page is blank, when I view the pages source I see this:

```
<?
    $test = "hello world";
    echo $test;
?>
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** 
Fixed thanks, I was an idiot and didn't open it with

Instead of wasting this thread for such a stupid mistake here is another question. 
Is there a version of Chrome or Firefox I can use to run my website but lock it in full screen and require a password to get out of it?

Comment: How about you dable in Linux, so much easier ;)

Comment: Apache & PHP are working very well on Windows. And there's nothing more easy than a WAMP or equivalent to begin development, even professionally. Ofc, this is an other question when you talk about hosting a high-traffic website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `<?php` tag instead of `<?`, this is often disabled in standard php installations.

BTW, to activate short tags, the property is

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in your php.ini.

Comment: For some reason I had it in my head that the tags where <?(open) ?>(close).
Thanks, that worked, can tell I have not used PHP in a while, feel like a right idiot now lol.

Comment: I had the same problem when I went back to PHP, they changed it with PHP4. You should read these articles : http://www.php.net/manual/en/appendices.php. Very interesting, begin with 4.X to 5.X article. Enjoy ! PHP has grown up a bit. Also you can always accept the answer if it's ok for you. Thanks.